# Image with white background causes watchOS system clock to disappear

Tags: swiftui, watchos, watchos-10

I'm develop a app using the new watchOS 10, I choose using TabView with tabViewStyle equals vertical page, so I can scroll over my app images and they show up in "full screen".
However, some images have a white background, the same color as watchOS system clock, which causes the clock to disappear.

I'm looking for some way to add a blur behind the system clock or change the color so the user can see the clock anytime he wants. If I add a button in the clock position, Top Bar Trailing, the clock moves to the center and end up with the same problem. For the color, I already try to change the AccentColor, but didn't influence the clock color